# How to show SourceTree and alrady existing repository and copy and updated version of it

Tags: git, version-control, fetch, atlassian-sourcetree

so I'm fairly new to version control and I'd like to get some help. My friend has uploaded a fairly large repo to VSO and I need to clone it. Although I already have almost an exact replica of that repo but with a few changes. How do I show SourceTree that this is the same repo and to simply go fetch the changes nad apply them? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

What about adding the repository using the new button and then fetch it?

Just verify that the remote is the same as the one you want to update from.